# Trying to move Boolean column logic from SQLITE to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, boolean

I am trying to move my Python application from my PC (which is using SQLITE3) to Heroku (Postgres). I have declared Boolean columns in my tables and, in SQLITE I need to give these a value of 0 or 1. However, I believe in Postgres this needs to be True or False.

Is there a way that this conversion can be done easily such that I can continue to develop on SQLITE and deploy to Postgres without changing the code.

I guess the bottom line is amending the columns to Int and constraining their values to 0 or 1 but is there an easier answer?

```
# For example with SQLITE (adminuser is a column of Users, described as 
# Boolean):- 
admin_user = Users.query.filter_by(club = form.club.data, adminuser = 1)" 

# For Postgres:-
admin_user = Users.query.filter_by(club = form.club.data, adminuser = 
True)"
```

Comment: "*develop on SQLITE and deploy to Postgres*" - that is a really bad idea and won't work. Especially because of SQLite's complete lack of proper data types (and the necessary checking of values)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name; what SQL package would you recommend I install locally to manage my development work?

Comment: You can install the same Postgres version locally as your production system has. Code developed locally will run the same of production system. But do not attempt performance testing locally.